# The ListView is not updated with the newest note added (making a Note app)

Tags: android, listview

I am currently making a Notepad application.
When I press a button to add a new note, it takes me to the note adding Activity.
However, when I click on finish, the note itself is not updated to the homepage ListView.
The ListView does have a row of items, but the title of the row does not appear.
What could be the problem?

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private ListView listview;
public static NoteAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Note> notesList;
private DatabaseHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    notesList = db.getAllNotes();
    adapter = new NoteAdapter(getApplicationContext(), notesList);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteAddClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Note note = db.getNote(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteViewClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", note.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("message", note.getContent());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            notesList.remove(i);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            db.deleteNote(notesList.get(i));
            return false;
        }
    });
}
 }
```

NoteViewClass.java

```
    public class NoteViewClass extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView title, message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_view_layout);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleViewTextView);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageViewTextView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String title_intent = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String message_intent = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    title.setText(title_intent);
    message.setText(message_intent);
}
}
```

NoteAddClass.java

```
    public class NoteAddClass extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText title, message;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_add_layout);

    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishButton);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    db.addNote(new Note(title.getText().toString(), message.getText().toString()));

    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

NoteAdapter.java

```
    public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTextView;
}

public NoteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Note note = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        //save viewholder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleRowTextView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(note.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notesManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_OF_NOTES = "notes";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_OF_NOTES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_OF_NOTES);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

//!--------- Below to Handle CRUD Operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete)--------------!

public void addNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle()); // Note Title
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, note.getContent()); // Note Message

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_OF_NOTES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

//accepts a single id and returns the corresponding row item to this ID
public Note getNote(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_OF_NOTES, new String[]
            { KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_CONTENT }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    //the first constructor, fetching the contents of the row
    Note note = new Note(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return note;
}

//returns all notes in an arraylist format
public ArrayList<Note> getAllNotes() {
    ArrayList<Note> noteArrayList = new ArrayList<Note>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OF_NOTES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Note note = new Note();
            note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            note.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            note.setContent(cursor.getString(2));

            // Adding contact to list
            noteArrayList.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return noteArrayList;
}

//returns the total number of notes in the database
public int getNotesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OF_NOTES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

//updates a single note object i the database
public int updateNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, note.getContent());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_OF_NOTES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(note.getId())});
}

//deleting a note
public void deleteNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_OF_NOTES, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(note.getId()) });
    db.close();
}
}
```

[image]

UPDATE

It gave me an IndexOutOfBounds exception on this line 
`db.deleteNote(notesList.get(i));` in MainActivity.java in `setOnItemLongClickListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an index out of bounds because you removed the note from the list, then use that same index to get the note from the list

```
notesList.remove(i); // root problem 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
db.deleteNote(notesList.get(i));
```

As for the titles not displaying, you need to check your database to see if the strings are stored, then verify that you are setting the title to the Note class, and then the getter method returns that string, and finally the Adapter is loading that string into the correct view.

If you want to do this slightly different, look into using a CursorAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter. This way, you can reload the cursor to the adapter when you update the database instead of trying to synchronize the two.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter notesList is not changing when You are doing **db.addNote** or **db.deleteNote**. This methods changes data in database but not in adapter list which is **notesList = db.getAllNotes();**

Do do it right You must after changes in db change list in adapter. For example add method to adapter like:

```
public void addToList(Note note){

  list.add(note);
  notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

And use it after adding to db:

```
Not note=new Note(title.getText().toString(), message.getText().toString());
db.addNote(note);
adapter.addToList(note);
```